# Change making program with currencys as a option not working

Tags: python-3.x

I was making a change making program for my class, the basic task was;

"Adjust your MakeChange program, so that the user first selects GBP, USD, or EUR. Then the program will ask how much change to make in the appropriate currency, i.e. "Please enter amount to change: $" For this purpose, assume all coinage is the same."

The original code was:

```
change = int(input("Change=:"))

print(change // 200,"£2")
change = change % 200

print(change // 100,"£1")
change = change % 100

print(change // 50,"50p")
change = change % 50

print(change // 20,"20p")
change = change % 20

print(change // 10,"10p")
change = change % 10
```

So basically getting a input from user and returning the change in pence
I need this to work but for USD - GBP and EUR so i tried;

```
print("RUNNING: Change Program v2 - 14/10/16")
print("Have Fun!")

# 1 Represents currency
100 = int(input("Define currency - USD/GBP/EUR")
USD = 1
GBP = 101
EUR = 100



if 100 > USD:
    print("You have chosen USD as your currency")
    Change = int(input("Please enter amount of change in pence")
    print(change // 200,"$2")
    change = change % 200

    print(change // 100,"$1")
    change = change % 100

    print(change // 50,"50p")
    change = change % 50

    print(change // 20,"20p")
    change = change % 20

    print(change // 10,"10p")
    change = change % 10



if 100 < GBP:
    print("You have chosen GBP as your currency")
    Change = int(input("Please enter amount of change in pence")
    print(change // 200,"£2")
    change = change % 200

    print(change // 100,"£1")
    change = change % 100

    print(change // 50,"50p")
    change = change % 50

    print(change // 20,"20p")
    change = change % 20

    print(change // 10,"10p")
    change = change % 10



if currency = 3:
    print("You have chosen EUR as your currency")
    Change = int(input("Please enter amount of change in pence")
    print(change // 200,"€2")
    change = change % 200

    print(change // 100,"€1")
    change = change % 100

    print(change // 50,"50p")
    change = change % 50

    print(change // 20,"20p")
    change = change % 20

    print(change // 10,"10p")
    change = change % 10
```

The program needs to use if/else/elif ect, please could you help me out

Comment: what is the problem you need help with and what have you tried so far?

Comment: the problem is that i cant get the if function to work so that when the user imputs a currency it then asks them to then input change and outpiuts in the currencys values the second code box is what i tried

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
# 1 Represents currency
100 = int(input("Define currency - USD/GBP/EUR")
USD = 1
GBP = 101
EUR = 100
```

write only

```
currency = input("Define currency - USD/GBP/EUR: ")
```

and instead of your three `if` statements write these three:

```
if currency == "USD":

if currency == "GPB":

if currency == "EUR":
```